# Making scheduled jobs in rails using sidekiq vs other background process gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backgroundworker, background-process, sidekiq

Currently I am working on a auction bidding web app. We used state machines to handle various status of auction. We need to trigger specific method when the auction start time is equal to current time. For that we used **sidekiq** gem.

Please give some suggestion on using sidekiq gem, whether we can handle more number of auctions at the same time. How sidekiq will manage these type of scheduled tasks?

Also, what other options we may try to accomplish these? Like what other gems/libraries we can try?

Please share some ideas in it. Thanks.

Comment: A quick google search will bring up a lot of information on job processing in Rails.  Take a look at ActiveJob which comes in Rails 4.2 and which gem's it supports (sidekiq, resque etc.)

Comment: Please read "[ask]". Your question is too broad. We're not here to give examples of using SideKiq, instead you can research and read their examples and other people's code to find out how they've used it. Asking us for other options to do similar things is also off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

sidekiq is best, because it uses threads (so much less memmory usage) and store job info in redis - so fast and not take main db resources

other solutions -

1. delayed_job - store job info in sql db
2. resque - store job info in redis but use processes instead of threads in sidekiq

Comment: While you're trying to help, the question is poorly asked because it's too broad and is soliciting suggestions for off-site libraries. Instead of answering, you should help the OP narrow the question and encourage searching on their own prior to asking.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not comfortable using threads in Sidekiq you can set this in sidekiq.yml.  Then you can run 2 sidekiq processes.  But it will use more memory

```
---
:concurrency: 1
```